# Why is quicksort's time complexity O(nlog n) expected, when there is a Theta(n) algorithm for median selection?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

Have there been any practical tests to see the overhead that we get when running Quicksort with the `O(n)` worst case algorithm by using the median of median approach to pick a splitting element and when using a `O(1)` worst case algorithm by picking a random splitting element?

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not match. Using median of medians to quicksort will get you `Theta(nlogn)` average and worst case complexity, with terrible constants. You can create a benchmark and test yourself how it will behave compared to a random choice, and run a statistic test, it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Following up on what @amit said, you can add a check to only do the median of median approach when your median algorithm is performing poorly.  With this you can keep the order of magnitude for both best and worst case `Theta(n log(n))` with good constants for the average case and bad ones for the worst case.  There is a tradeoff where the better you make the average case, the worse the worst case will be.